# Sort a list by specific location in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sorting

I've got a list of strings and I want to sort this by a specific part of the string only, not the full string.

I would like to sort the entire list only focusing on the second last part 
When I use the regular sort() functions I have the issue that it sorts using the full string value.
I've tried using the 'key=' option with split('_') but somehow I am not able to get it working.

```py
# Key to sort profile files
def sortprofiles(item):
        item.split('_')[-2]

# Input
local_hostname = 'ma-tsp-a01'
profile_files = ['/path/to/file/TSP_D01_ma-tsp-a01\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_D02_ma-tsp-a02\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_ASCS00_ma-tsp-a01\n', \
'/path/ato/file/TSP_DVEBMGS03_ma-tsp-a03\n', \
'/path/to/file/TSP_DVEBMGS01_ma-tsp-a01\n']
# Do stuff
profile_files = [i.split()[0] for i in profile_files]
profile_files.sort(key=sortprofiles)
print(profile_files)
```

I currently get the following error message:
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

I would like to get the list sorted as: `['/path/to/file/TSP_ASCS00_ma-tsp-a01', '/path/to/file/TSP_D01_ma-tsp-a01', '/path/to/file/TSP_D02_ma-tsp-a02', '/path/to/file/TSP_DVEBMGS01_ma-tsp-a01', '/path/ato/file/TSP_DVEBMGS03_ma-tsp-a03']`

Comment: You need to `return` the value from function `sortprofiles`, check my answer below :) @nsolthe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the value on how you want to split on, you need to return it from `sortprofiles` function and then your function will work as expected!

Earlier you were not returning anything, which is equivalent to returning `None` and when you try to run a comparison operator like `<` on None, you get the exception `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

So the below will work

```
def sortprofiles(item):
    #You need to return the key you want to sort on
    return item.split('_')[-2]

local_hostname = 'ma-tsp-a01'
profile_files = ['/path/to/file/TSP_D01_ma-tsp-a01\n',
'/path/to/file/TSP_D02_ma-tsp-a02\n',
'/path/to/file/TSP_ASCS00_ma-tsp-a01\n',
'/path/ato/file/TSP_DVEBMGS03_ma-tsp-a03\n',
'/path/to/file/TSP_DVEBMGS01_ma-tsp-a01\n']

print(sorted(profile_files, key=sortprofiles))
```

The output will then be

```
['/path/to/file/TSP_ASCS00_ma-tsp-a01\n', '/path/to/file/TSP_D01_ma-tsp-a01\n', '/path/to/file/TSP_D02_ma-tsp-a02\n', '/path/to/file/TSP_DVEBMGS01_ma-tsp-a01\n', '/path/ato/file/TSP_DVEBMGS03_ma-tsp-a03\n']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=lambda#lambda-expressions) and try

```
profile_files = sorted(profile_files, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[1])
```

Each string in the list is split based on the occurrence of `_` and the second part is considered for sorting.

But this may not work if the strings are not in the format that you expect.

Comment: @J...S: Thanks for the quick answer. I am not 100% sure if the first part of the string always looks what I expect, but I'm sure the last part always looks this pattern. So to make sure it works to my situation I changed this to `sort(key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-2])`. In my special case I prefer to use 'sort()' as I have to make sure the list sorted once I have done it

Comment: For what it's worth, this works because lambda function actually does the same thing you forgot to do in your original function, `return` the value :)